# Polynomial with n real roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $P(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{1}x + 1$ where $a_i$ are nonnegative and real. Assume $P$ has $n$ real roots.

Prove $P(2) \geq 3^n$.

I thought I had a good idea about rewriting $P$ as $(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$. The fact that the roots are real means that you can order them. Choose the largest root, $\alpha_k$, then $2-\alpha_k$ would have the smallest such value among the $\alpha_i$. And so we would have $P(2) \geq (2-\alpha_k)^n$.

But I haven't been able to think of a way to compare it with $3^n$.

Comment: You could try working up to it by degree and see if you see a pattern in the proofs; it's easy in the linear (and constant) case. The quadratic case seems doable - you want $x^2+ax + 1$ to have real roots which, from the discriminant, means $a\geq 4$ and hence $P(2)\geq 2^2 + 4\cdot 2 + 1 = 9$. It does start to get trickier in higher degrees though... (i.e. I have no immediate idea)

Comment: Quite right, very tricky to follow that for higher degrees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof follows from the following Lemma:

**Lemma** If $0<a \leq 1 \leq b$ then 
$$(2+a)(2+b) \geq 3(2+ab)$$

**Proof:**
$$(2+a)(2+b) \geq 3(2+ab) \Leftrightarrow \\
4+2a+2b+ab \geq 6+3ab \Leftrightarrow \\
0 \geq 2-2a-2b+2ab \Leftrightarrow \\
0 \geq 2(a-1)(b-1)
$$

QED Lemma

Now, lets solve the problem. Let $b_i=-\alpha_1$, and we can assume without loss of generality that $b_1 \leq b_2 \leq ... \leq b_n$.

As $b_1 \cdot .. \cdot b_n=1$ it follows that 
$$b_n \geq 1 \\
b_1\cdot ... \cdot b_k \leq 1$$

Then, by repeadely applying the previous lemma, we get

$$(2+b_1)(2+b_2)(2+b_3)\cdot ... \cdot (2+b_n) \geq \\
3(2+b_1b_2)(2+b_3)\cdot ... \cdot (2+b_n) \geq \\
3^2(2+b_1b_2b_3)\cdot ... \cdot (2+b_n) \geq \\
....\\
3^{k-1}(2+b_1b_2b_3...b_k)(2+b_{k+1}\cdot ... \cdot (2+b_n) \geq \\
...\\
3^{n-1}(2+b_1b_2b_3...b_n)=3^n \\
$$

**Much simpler second solution:**

If $b_1,..,b_n$ are non-negative numbers then by the AM-GM inequality:

$$2+b_i = 1+1+b_i \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{b_i}$$

Therefore
$$(2+b_1)(2+b_2)(2+b_3)\cdot ... \cdot (2+b_n) \geq 3^n  \sqrt[3]{b_1b_2...b_n}=3^n$$

Comment: Those are great solutions, thank you!

Comment: I just mulled this over- for the second solution, the $b_i$ are roots of $P(x)$ - we can't assume they are non-negative can we?

Comment: @BoRel $b_i=-\alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are the roots. Since all coefficients are non-negative, the roots cannot be positive. This means that $b_i$ are positive.